# how do I animate transitions between multiple XML files?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have one activity for my app, which uses multiple XML files and setContentView to transition between each page. I want to add animations to the transition, however setContentView always puts the layout ontop of the other (and removes the other one). I've googled for about an hour, and I can't find anything that works with multiple XML files. I found a way to use addContentView to add the layout to the page, but I forgot how to and have been searching for that again, with no success.

How would I go about animating the transition between XML files?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below example:

slide_in_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="true">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" android:duration="400">
    </translate>
</set>
```

slide_out_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="true" >
    <translate
        android:duration="400"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" >
    </translate>

</set>
```

In startActivity() use following code:

```
startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, TargetActivity.class));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
finish();
```

Comment: if I change the view whilist in the same activity, will this still make the views transition? doesn't look like it will

Comment: @de_veloper, are you use fragments?